# How can I know if the format of a string is the same as the format of an input value? in java

Tags: java, string, date, datetime-format, java-time

> First, thanks, Elder Developer, I’m super newbie... and sorry I don't speak English well.... so.. understand my sentence..

I want to know the way what compare a's format with DateStringFormat.

Example:

```
boolean CompareFormat(String inputValue, DateTimeFormatter format) {
    String gettedFormat = ~~~.getFormat(inputValue);
    if (format.toString().equals(gettedFormat)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

It’s just, I think...

1. get formatted input String value.
2. change formatted value to format
   (i think, changed value change to format again it doesn't change
   / inputvalue : 19900202T0001 -> change to format (yyyyMMddThhmm)-> result :  19900202T0001)
3. if inputvalue is same with value changed to format then return true; else 
   false;

but I can't get the result that I think.

I tried

```
            System.out.println("format : " + format);
            System.out.println("value : "+value);
            LocalDate changedDateString = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
            System.out.println("changed Value : " + changedDateString);
            System.out.println("changed Value : " + formatter.format(changedDateString));
```

Output:

```
format : yyyyMMdd'T'hhmm
value : 20170616T0023
changed Value : 2017-06-16
18:19:14.053 ERROR ServiceTask - Exception caught.
```

Comment: There’s a mismatch between your format string `yyyyMMdd'T'hhmm` and your choice of type, `LocalDate`. A `LocalDate` is a date only, it does not include time of day (hours and minutes). So either use `LocalDateTime` instead or leave out `HHmm` from your format pattern string. BTW, that should probably be capital `HH` for hour in the interval 0 through 23.

Comment: You will be able to recognize a limited number of possible formats and use appropriate formatters. You cannot recognize and handle all possible formats. The classical example is 11/06/2017: to some it means November 6, to others 11 June.

Comment: @Ole V.V. ahh... thank you Older. i understand what u said. i was solve as other way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure precisely what you are trying to obtain, but I thought I’d throw in a suggestion. For your Boolean method to check whether a given input string matches a given format, I think the easy check is to try parsing the string with the format and see if it succeeds:

```
public static boolean compareFormat(String inputValue, DateTimeFormatter format) {
    try {
        format.parse(inputValue);
        // parsing succeeded; so the format seems to match
        return true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use like this, for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'hhmm");
    System.out.println(compareFormat("20170616T0023", dtf));
```

This prints `true`. On the other hand, `compareFormat("2017-06-16", dtf)` yields false.

The method doesn’t check the aspect I touched on in a comment, whether the input looks like a `LocalDate` (without hours and minutes) or a `LocalDateTime` (as in the example) or something else.

The code example in your question throws a `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`, which I suppose is the reason for the line `18:19:14.053 ERROR ServiceTask - Exception caught.`. This is because you are trying to format a `LocalDate` with a formatter that includes `hh` and `mm`. `hh` means clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12) and is usually used with an AM/PM marker as in “9:15 AM”. Anyway, a `LocalDate` only contains a date, no hours nor minutes, so it cannot be formatted with your `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: ahh @Ole V.V. thank you very much what ur answer. i can understand a little : ) hahaha.. can't use LocalDate as Hour and Minutes.